# Поместить текст в картинку HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Начал потихоньку разбираться с HTML и CSS сразу подкатила небольшая работка. Так как я только учусь всех нюансов не знаю. Имеется меню в котором текст должен быть написан на звездочках, звездочки(они разного цвета) являются картинками и требуется поместить ссылку в них. Уже пытался это сделать с помощью position: relative и absolute. Выравнивал текст по первой ссылке и получалось так, что 1 ссылка становилась ровно в центр, а остальные 4 съезжали влево с помощью padding исправить это не удавалось, так как кол-во букв разное и все равно в какую-то сторону ссылки съезжали.

Кусочек кода HTML:

```
            <nav>
                <li><img src="img/star1.png" alt=""><a href="#">Avaleht</a></li>
                <li><img src="img/star1.png" alt=""><a href="#">Broneeri</a></li>
                <li><img src="img/star1.png" alt=""><a href="#">Reeglid</a></li>
                <li><img src="img/star1.png" alt=""><a href="#">Hinnad</a></li>
                <li><img src="img/star1.png" alt=""><a href="#">Galerii</a></li>
            </nav>
```

Здесь картинки одинаковые, так как 5 с разными цветами прикладывать я думаю не имеет смысла.

CSS:

```
nav {
   float: right;
}

nav li {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}

nav img {
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
}

nav li a {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   right: 15px;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-shadow: 5px 6px 10px #000000;
   font-size: 27px;
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

Может это у меня руки не из того места растут, но вроде я делаю все правильно. Возможно это можно выровнять через child, но я уверен есть более простой способ.

Картинка:[image: Картинка]

У меня получается вот такая вот фигня: [image]

P.S. каждая ссылка должна быть в центре звезды.

Answer (score 4):

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 25px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <li><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG41531.png" alt=""><a href="#">Avaleht</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG41531.png" alt=""><a href="#">Broneeri</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG41531.png" alt=""><a href="#">Reeglid</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG41531.png" alt=""><a href="#">Hinnad</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG41531.png" alt=""><a href="#">Galerii</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG41531.png" alt=""><a href="#">Galerii</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG41531.png" alt=""><a href="#">Galerii</a></li>
  </nav>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Только лучше бы вместо img использовать background.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я делал в соответсвии как попросили. Он привел пример свой, я исправил.

Comment: Можно использовать не отступы left и top у <a>, которые поломают верстку, если в ссылке будет несколько строк или текст будет короче, а transform: translate(-50%, -50%); left: 50%; top: 50%; text-align: center

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Проверю чутка позже. P.S. Использовать background вместо img крайне не удобно, так как звездочки должны быть разные, а для каждого <a> добавлять свои стили это я считаю лишней нагрузкой.